# PDO fetchColumn() and fetchObject() which is better and proper usage

Tags: pdo

It's been bugging me, I have a query which returns a **single row** and I need to get their corresponding column value.

```
//Retrieve Ticket Information to Database
$r = db_query("SELECT title, description, terms_cond, image, social_status, sched_stat FROM giveaway_table WHERE ticket_id = :ticket_id",
    array(
        ':ticket_id' => $ticket_id
));
```

There are two ways that I can get data which is, by using **fetchColumn()** and **fetchObject()**

**fetchObject()**

```
$object = $r->fetchObject();

$ticket_info[] = $object->title;
$ticket_info[] = $object->description;
$ticket_info[] = $object->terms_cond;
$ticket_info[] = $object->image;
$ticket_info[] = $object->social_status;
$ticket_info[] = $object->sched_stat;
```

**fetchColumn()**

```
$title = $r->fetchColumn() //Returns title column value
$description = $r->fetchColumn(1) //Returns description column value
```

Was wondering, which one is better, or are there any pros and cons about this stuff?

**if possible,** can you guys also suggest the **best** way (if there's any) on how to retrieve all columns that's been selected in a query and store it into an array with less line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two ways that I can get data which is, by using fetchColumn() and fetchObject()

really? what about `fetch()`?

There is a [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) where you can find everything you need

Comment: Ehhhhhhh I mean, there are only two ways that I only know how to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know pros and cons of using it. In my project I often used fetching as array rather than object. It was more comfortable. But if you make ORM projects then maybe it would be better to use fetchObject and make it your object not a std_class. You could make a contructor that has one parametr which is stdClass and make your object from this class

Answering your other question you can fetch all columns using fetchAll();

Follow this link to learn more about this function http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

More about abstract database layer you can find here -> http://www.doctrine-project.org/